# How to Spell-Check LaTeX in multiple languages / language variants

Tags: latex, spell-checking

I am writing a PhD Thesis / Dissertation and would like to be able to spell-check the thing.  The problem is that I'm required to write it in UK English, while many of my quotations are written in US English.  This makes spell-checking quite a pain.

Is there a way to tag sections of LaTeX text as being UK English / US English, and have a spell-checker either respond to that tagging or skip the sections which aren't in the particular language variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/untex.html

**Usage**

```
Here are some example uses:

  untex myfile.tex
  untex file1 file2 file3
  spelltex myfile.tex
  spelltex file1 file2 file3
```

If the environment variable SPELLDIR is defined, it gives the directory containing the local spelling file to be used, otherwise *"British" spelling is used*.

So at least that way you could run different spell checkers on different files, assuming you've split up your document on chapters or similar?

Alternatively, just run it twice - once in each English, and there can't be that many errors. You could even add a txt file of words to ignore, or even add them to the 'custom' dictionary for the spellcheckers...

Comment: Thanks, Mark!  The problem is that the literature review section alone is in the tens of thousands of words, with quotes interspersed.  I was hoping that I could somehow switch between different SPELLDIRs, engaging the appropriate dictionary over a single file.  The alternative is splitting out each US quote into its own file, which is possible, but makes for painful editing of the chapter.  I *have* split it into multiple chapters, however, and it's primarily the literature review chapter which is painful to check.  I was just looking for a better solution.

Comment: Annoyingly it looks like it's possible in MS Word (http://thedailyreviewer.com/windowsapps/view/how-do-i-spell-check-a-single-word-document-in-two-languages-105119219) but I can't find anything else better in LaTeX, unfortunately.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  Yes - I'd seen the functionality in Word (although it's kinda clunky, in that you can't *tell* that a particular section is tagged as being in an alternate language).  There's no way I'm trying to write this up in Word, though - talk about a painful app to use!

Comment: There are LaTeX to Word converters...but I'd be a little sceptical about their reliability :)

Comment: I have tried some of them, just to be able to share with others ... but they're quite flaky.  It's a good idea, though - I could spellcheck in Word that way, but I'd still have to go through Word and tag everything as belonging to a particular language, rather than being able to do so within LaTeX.

Comment: Accepting Mark's answer as the best that can be done at the moment.  I'm going to ask the same question over at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20057/ in the hopes that somebody has a more ideal solution (although I submit in a few weeks, so it's a bit late, really).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Emacs, take a look at [`flyspell-babel.el`](https://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Emacs/).